# Lookat matrix inverts pitch and yaw movement

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I am calculating the lookat matrix by hand and while it works with directional movement (forwards, backwards, etc.) when I move the mouse cursor it rotates the camera in the opposite direction.

```cpp
glm::mat4 Camera::GetViewMatrix() {
    // now we find our coordinate system for a UVN camera
    // whatever the camera is looking at needs to be -z --> in NDC space, +z points out of screen

    // the point that the camera is currently looking at
    glm::vec3 target = position + front;

    // negation of vector pointing out of the camera's face
    glm::vec3 n = glm::normalize(position - target);

    // vector pointing to camera's right
    glm::vec3 u = glm::normalize(glm::cross(worldUp, n));

    // vector pointing to camera's relative up
    glm::vec3 v = glm::normalize(glm::cross(n, u));

    // this changes basis from camera space to world space (works correctly)
    /* glm::mat4 rotate( */
    /*     u.x,  v.x,  n.x,  0.0f, */
    /*     u.y,  v.y,  n.y,  0.0f, */
    /*     u.z,  v.z,  n.z,  0.0f, */
    /*     0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f */
    /* ); */

    // this inverse changes from world space to camera space (works incorrectly)
    glm::mat4 rotate(
        u.x,  u.y,  u.z,  0,
        v.x,  v.y,  v.z,  0,
        n.x,  n.y,  n.z,  0,
        0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    );

    // moves the camera back to the origin
    glm::mat4 trans(glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), -position));

    // to go from camera space to world space we rotate and then translate
    // so we do the opposite to get from world space to camera space
    return rotate * trans;
}
```

The code works correctly if I use the commented out matrix (camera space to world space), but I thought that we are transforming from world space to camera space?

Here is how the direction vector is calculated:

```cpp
void Camera::updateCameraVectors() {
    glm::vec3 direction;
    direction.x = cos(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));
    direction.y = sin(glm::radians(pitch));
    direction.z = sin(glm::radians(yaw)) * cos(glm::radians(pitch));

    front = glm::normalize(direction);
    right = glm::normalize(glm::cross(front, worldUp));
    up    = glm::normalize(glm::cross(right, front));
}
```

And the pitch and yaw:

```cpp
void Camera::ProcessMouseMovement(float xoffset, float yoffset, bool constrainPitch) {
    xoffset *= sensitivity;
    yoffset *= sensitivity;

    yaw += xoffset;
    pitch += yoffset;

    if (constrainPitch) {
        if (pitch > 89.0f)
            pitch = 89.0f;
        if (pitch < -89.0f)
            pitch = -89.0f;
    }

    updateCameraVectors();
}
```

Comment: out of curiosity, why not call glm::lookat?

Comment: That's essentially what I'm trying to recreate. This is more for learning than actual use.